# Accessing system call from within a new created system call

Tags: c, minix

I'm working on Minix 3.

I'm implementing a new system call called do_identify that returns either the id of the current process or the parent process. Here's the definition of the system call under *`/usr/src/servers/pm/misc.c`* and it's library, which I named it ***identifylib.h***, under *`/usr/include`*:

**Definition:**

```
PUBLIC int do_identify()
{
    int identifier = m_in.m1_i1;
    if(identifier == 1)
    {
        printf("Current Process ID = %d\n", getpid());
        return getpid();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Parent Process ID = %d\n", getppid());
        return getppid();
    }
}
```

**Library:**

```
#include <lib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

PUBLIC int identify (int process)
{
    message m;
    m.m1_i1 = process;
    return ( _syscall(PM_PROC_NR, IDENTIFY, &m) );
}
```

Now, when I test it, i get the following error:

> undefined reference to getppid

Am I invoking incorrectly this function? or Am I not supposed to invoke this function within the system call? I don't know what it is supposed to mean on minix.

Here is the test file: ***test_id.c***

```
#include <identifylib.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Process ID = %d\n" identify(1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On Linux and most other Unixes system calls cannot be called kernel side. It could be likewise on Minix.

Comment: `getpid` and `getppid` are standard C library functions, which invoke system calls. The standard C library is not available to the kernel. You need to get the PID information directly within the kernel (see the `getpid` system call implementation to figure how to do that).

Comment: @Mohit Jain: ok, I was a little liberal with that comment. Let's say: the standard Unix C Interface library (unistd.h). The functions are usually found in libc though, however you want to label it.

Comment: @isedev so, what I'm looking for is for the files within libc, which are, getpid.c and getppid.c?

Comment: No, the libc files will be the user space code which performs the system call. What you need is to understand how the `getpid` / `getppid` system call themselves are implemented so you can get the PID and PPID as needed within your system call implementation.

Comment: Something like this perhaps https://github.com/minix3/minix/blob/master/minix/servers/pm/getset.c